# Trying to write a DLL for wallhack usw

Tags: c++, dll, detours

I'm trying to write a DLL file that I can inject into a game. I'm pretty far but when I try to compile the code I always get the error

```
Error LNK2001 Unresolved external symbol "" unsigned char * __cdecl Detours :: X86 :: DetourFunction (unsigned char *, unsigned char *, enum Detours :: X86Option) "(? DetourFunction @ X86 @ Detours @@ YAPAEPAE0W4X86Option @ 2 @@ Z ) ".
```

The detours folder I use is from here:
https://github.com/Nukem9/detours

but the Detours.h file was broken because I couldn't use  `uint8_t` so I replaced the code in there with the code from that file:
https://github.com/Nukem9/VMWareClient/blob/master/vmware_client/detours/Detours.h
The codline where I think the problem is:

```
oEndScene = (EndScene)Detours::X86::DetourFunction((uint8_t*)d3d9Device[42], (uint8_t*)hkEndScene);
```

but for those who are interested, I can post the whole code here. Just tell me in the comments. The whole code is 256 lines long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just replace function definition:

```
uintptr_t DetourFunction(uintptr_t Target, uintptr_t Detour, X86Option Options = X86Option::USE_JUMP);
```

with

```
uint8_t     *DetourFunction(uint8_t *Target, uint8_t *Detour, X86Option Options = X86Option::USE_JUMP);
```

Why can't you use `uint8_t`? Can't you just add:

```
typedef unsigned char      uint8_t;
```

Comment: I tried what you said but it didn't work so I changed the detours.h file back to the normal one and replaced uint8_t with uintptr_r now it works fine I think